# Rails - Loop through csv separated by bars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a CSV document with one column and 1000 rows. Each row has a string of data which is seperated by "|".

**For example**

```
BOB|MARLEY|306336|Friday|  9:00AM|02 DIS 2|HELE TP 1|PARRA|JULIA|20 Jul 2018|TOMPSON|TORI|21332|NA|AUS|4214|||0400 000 000|zzz11@bigpond.com|.0000|NULL|NULL|0|QLD|F|2016-06-22 00:00:00.000|
```

I need to loop through each row then split the string into another array. I then need to loop through each of those arrays.

**Currently I have**

```
csv_text = open('https://res.cloudinary.com/thypowerhouse/raw/upload/v1534642033/rackleyswimming/HVL_SCHOOL.csv')
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers=>true)

    csv.each do |row|
      new_row = row.map(&:inspect).join
      new_row = new_row.delete! '[]'
      new_row = new_row.gsub('|', '", "')
      new_row = new_row.split(',')
      puts new_row 
    end
```

Don't know if I'm heading in the right direction?

Comment: Use `col_sep: “|”` option. See http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#new

Answer (score 4):

You can use [col_sep](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-CSV+and+Character+Encodings+-28M17n+or+Multilingualization-29) to separate the data of each row:

```
require "csv"

CSV.foreach("HVL_SCHOOL.csv", headers: true, col_sep: "|") do |row|
  # Your code here, trait your data
end
```

Every `row` on the scope of `CSV#foreach` (previus example) will be a [CSV::Row](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html) that can be treated as an array because it has `enumerable` as included module.

I think with this you can do what you want with this data.